# Swift 3 - WKWebView Load Local HTML not loading resource files

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, wkwebview

I was download my website from online to store in xcode project with a sub-folder and want to run in WKWebView locally. I found the webview loaded webpage miss all CSS/JS/Images resources. I search around the internet and still not working. Is webpage inside relative url incorrect or my code to get the Main Bundle location problem? Anyone can help. Thanks.

[Xcode Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeBc8.png)

[HTML Page Contents Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HM9mb.png)

I wrote this code to load WKWebView

```
let htmlFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "provisiontech", ofType: "htm")
let html = try? String(contentsOfFile: htmlFile!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
let baseURL = Bundle.main.resourceURL!.appendingPathComponent("pvtc")
webView.loadHTMLString(html!, baseURL: baseURL)
```

Answer (score 2):

The webview has no access to the resource folder. You should use [loadFileURL(_:allowingReadAccessTo:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1414973-loadfileurl) instead. Preloading the data is not neccessary, e.g.:

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "provisiontech", ofType: "htm")

webView.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo:
    Bundle.main.resourceURL!.appendingPathComponent("pvtc"))
```

Edit: If the webview still cannot access the resources, you should consider whether putting the page and all resources into the same folder.