# Load local resources along with HTML string in WKwebView (SWIFT)?

Tags: html, ios, swift, wkwebview

I have an html string(which i got from an api response). Also i have some js file, css file, images and fonts on the app bundle.

I need to load these files along with the html string in WKWebView

[the html string look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1KNY.png)

[the app bundle look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HV93c.png)

[image: bundle folder expanted]

[My question similar to this :](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/113910)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on "use folder reference" option instead of "create groups" while adding the resources files and folders into bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Create a html below like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no">
        <meta name="supported-color-schemes" content="light dark">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="editor" contentEditable="true" placeholder="" class="placeholder"></div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="rich_editor.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Load your html and css file in the html, I have used `rich_editor.js` and `style.css`

Load created html to webview like this

```
webView.loadFileURL(documentsUrl, allowingReadAccessTo: documentsUrl.deletingLastPathComponent())
```

Using below function insert your Html string that obtained from API

```
public func runJS(_ js: String, handler: ((String) -> Void)? = nil) {
        webView.evaluateJavaScript(js) {(result, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("WKWebViewJavascriptBridge Error: \(String(describing: error)) - JS: \(js)")
                handler?("")
                return
            }
            
            guard let handler = handler else { return }
            if let resultBool = result as? Bool {
                handler(resultBool ? "true" : "false")
                return
            }
            if let resultInt = result as? Int {
                handler("\(resultInt)")
                return
            }
            if let resultStr = result as? String {
                handler(resultStr)
                return
            }
            handler("") // no result
        }
    }
```

To call this function

```
runJS("RE.insertHTML('yourHtmlString')")
```

Comment: I have multiple css files, how can I load multiple css files

Comment: Is it static or dynamic css files?

Comment: those are static, please check the images in the question. I'm upated the question

Comment: Load all the css files that we imported already for style.css

Comment: okey!!. so you are saying that ,loading style.css will call other css files

Comment: actually this is my problem.. please look into it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45801178/swift-3-wkwebview-load-local-html-not-loading-resource-files

Comment: I found the solution. No code is required. while adding the resources files and folders into bundle Click on **"use folder reference"** option instead of **"create groups"**